# Azure Blob Lease and release

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage

```
string uri = "myurl";
string blobstatus = GetBlobStatus(uri);
if (blobstatus != LeaseStatus.Locked.ToString())
{
    string response = AquireBlob(uri);
    //process data.
    string abc = ":em";
    ReleaseBlob(response, uri);
}
```

Above is my code for leasing and releasing locks on blob. I'm looking at this method to use for multi-instance worker role where I want to run a specific code after `x` interval of time, as multiple instances could execute the code at same time.

The problem is that I manage to get the `LeaseId` properly but when the second instance checks blob lease status it is always unspecified. Why it is so? any clues?

I followed the following link for getting a head start.

[Leasing Windows Azure Blobs Using the Storage Client Library - blog.smarx.com](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/leasing-windows-azure-blobs-using-the-storage-client-library)

Comment: What's the version of storage client library are you using? Also are you executing your code against storage emulator?

Comment: version of library is 1.7 .. by emulator do you mean development storage? no i am running on cloud storage.

Comment: Windows Azure Storage 2.0 is out now, and it has native support for leases.  You don't have to include the Smarx code.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/10/29/introducing-windows-azure-storage-client-library-2-0-for-net-and-windows-runtime.aspx

Answer (score 7):

I think your approach should not rely on checking the blob status first and based on that decide whether to acquire lease or not. You should always try and acquire the lease and capture the exception thrown in that process. That way if this code is running in multi-instance environment, only one instance will be able to acquire the lease (and other instances will just throw an error).

Comment: Right! Testing first is an anti-pattern, like `if (file.exists) delete(file)`. It adds a race condition to your code. Just try to acquire a lease and handle the failure.

Answer (score -2):

Good suggestions.. i solved the problem. found out that in fact that LeaseStatus property is not good and never returns results.
I had to get status by putting in web request and then i could get a right result.